# How to add specific prefix to the logging output in Rust?

Tags: logging, rust

I have an object and want every logging output to be prefixed with some states of the object. But adding prefix for every logging statement is very inconvenient. Is there any simple way to implement it?

Below is the sample code.

```rust
use log::info;

struct Obj {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
}

impl Obj {
    // can I use `info!("receive {} from {}", item, from);` for simplicity?
    fn call_me(&self, item: i32, from: String) {
        info!("[id: {}][name: {}] receive {} from {}", self.id, self.name, item, from);
    }
    // ...many methods
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The `tracing` crate from the `tokio` project has a built-in `instrument` which can be used on a function. Check out [their blog post](https://tokio.rs/blog/2019-08-tracing/). But it is a whole new beast to tame; you've been warned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a macro for this:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! log {
    ($sel:ident, $s:literal, $($arg:tt)*)
    =>
    (info!(concat!("[id: {}] [name: {}] ", $s), $sel.id, $sel.name, $($arg)*));
}

struct Obj {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
}

impl Obj {
    fn call_me(&self, item: i32, from: String) {
        log!(self, "receive {} from {}", item, from);
    }
}
```

It's not perfect, as you still need to pass `self`, but I'm not sure you can do better.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=adc084d2d0bc15f095a8e349ee8a5c60)